# google maps Uncaught ReferenceError: ZERO_RESULTS is not defined

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I donot understand why do I get this error because ZERO_RESULTS is a  constant defined by google maps api

Comment: @Dustin Laine

if (status==ZERO_RESULTS)                   {
                     alert("NO Results");
                     return;
                   }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an enumeration, not simply text.

```
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.ZERO_RESULTS) {
        //Nadda
    }
});
```

Comment: can you look into my other question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5968035/google-maps-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-start-location-of-undefine

Comment: the other question that I have posted regarding google maps here is the link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5968035/google-maps-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-start-location-of-undefine